# Visual Studio 2015 C# How to auto implement interface as a propfull

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interface, customization, quickaction

Resharper has this ability but I don't want to buy it for just that.

At the moment when I auto implement a interface in a class it formats all the properties as get and set with throw new not implemented exception.

Is there some way to modify how visual studio auto implements interfaces?

I'd like it to auto create a propfull like below based on the interface property name from the interface as a visual studio quick action;

```
private int num;
public int Num 
{
    get
    {
        return num;
    }
    set
    {
        num = value;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are looking for _snippets_ Just Google and you'll find tons of info. You can write your own snippet as you like. *Edit: And I'd recommend you to use `private int _num;` for declaring private fields. That's the common convention.